# How can I Implement the library GMP.mpz to generate big numbers in Pike?

Tags: factorial, gmp, bignum, pike

When I enter the command:

> pow(9,999999);

I obtain the following:

```
Bad argument 1 to pow(). Exponent too large.
Unknown program: pow(Gmp.mpz(999999))
-:1: 9->pow(@0=Gmp.mpz(999999))
HilfeInput:1: HilfeInput()->___HilfeWrapper()
```

Somebody would be able to indicate me how implementing the library efficaciously GMP.mpz, for example, to calculate 9 ^999999 or the factorial of 500000.
In advance thank you very much for your help.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Was 15 years since I used pike, so this is only possible answer:

1) maybe you need pike compiled with bignum support: https://pike.lysator.liu.se/docs/man/chapter_3.html#1 and then you  can use
pow() with arbitrary integers.

2) Alternatively perhaps Math module can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this limitation is hard-coded in Pike sources: `static void mpzmod_pow(INT32 args)` in `src/modules/Gmp/mpz_glue.c`. The sources obtainable from here:
 [Pike sources](https://pike.lysator.liu.se/download/)

Comment: `pike --info` gives info about the build. My pike says, among other stuff: `Features......auto_bignum` and the problem still happens.

Comment: Also `Math` module doesn't seem to be made for exponentiation.